# How to open Lightning component in new window

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have linked my lightning component with Quick action button, my requirement is I want to open lightning component in a new window.
How should I achieve this

Comment: new browser tab window or as new tab in service console App?

Comment: new browser tab window

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation).

**Target component**

should implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable`

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
Test
</aura:component>
```

Add to your **quick action component**

```html
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

And how to navigate from your **quick action controller**

```js
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__helloTarget',
            },
            state: {
                "c__firstname": "John"
            }
        };

        var navService = component.find("navService");
        event.preventDefault();
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

This code directs you to `/lightning/cmp/c__helloTarget?c__firstname=John`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `detail page button` with URL:

[image]

URL:

```
/lightning/cmp/c__MyCompName?c__att1=some_value
```

When you add this to record page layout, it will open component directly. You can also add parameters (all parameters should start with `c__`). Your component can read parameters through state in isUrlAddressable.

Note: This is URL hack and will work as long as URLs template dont change.

Comment: This opens in same window not in a new browser tab window.

Comment: Yes true. I think this is maximum we can get upto if we dont want to see the quick action modal. If you can use quick action, you get generated URL from page reference and use `window.open(URL,'_blank')`

Comment: @salesforce-sas I am trying to achieve something similar here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302538/calling-lightning-component-through-custom-button can you please help me what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Here are two Quick Action Button Lightning Component solutions to either open a pop-up window or new browser tab with a Visualforce Page (or whatever URL you want to redirect to):

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.openPage}" value="{!this}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller (to open pop-up window):

```
({
    openPage : function(component,event){
        var w = 1020;
        var h = screen.height-120;
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = 0;
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        //Open Pop-up Window with Visualforce Page
        window.open('/apex/YOUR_VISUALFORCE_PAGE?id='+recordId, 'Sales Contract', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
        //Close Action Button Modal
        $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
    }
})
```

Controller (to open new browser tab):

```
({
    openPage : function(component,event){
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        //Open New Browser Tab with Visualforce Page
        window.open('/apex/YOUR_VISUALFORCE_PAGE?id='+recordId,'_blank');
        //Close Action Button Modal
        $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
    }
})
```